# Checking if a DIFFERENT app is granted a permission

Tags: android, permissions

I've read around the internet for two options to check if an app is granted a permission or not.

Option 1:

```
getPackageManager().checkPermission(permission_string, packageName);
```

Option 2:

```
(PackageInfo.requestedPermissionsFlag[i] & PackageInfo.REQUESTED_PERMISSION_GRANTED) != 0
```

I'm running on Android 11. I'm implementing a mechanism that upon clicking an app, the permissions state will be checked and if a permission is not allowed, the user will be prompt to allow it. I'm only checking this for "advanced" permissions, meaning, permissions that requires the user to allow them from settings screen, such as manage external storage (for android 11), drawOverlay, writeSettings and such. Anyway, this is the code I'm using:

```
try {
            PackageInfo pi = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(currAppInfo.getName(), PackageManager.GET_PERMISSIONS);
            for(int i=0; i<pi.requestedPermissions.length; i++)
            {
                String perm = pi.requestedPermissions[i];
                
                PermissionInfo permi = getPackageManager().getPermissionInfo(perm, PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
                if(getPackageManager().checkPermission(perm, currAppInfo.getName()) == 0)
                    continue;
                if(AdvancedPermissionHandler.isAdvancedPermission(permi))
                {
                    AdvancedPermissionHandler.openSettingsPage(permi, currAppInfo.getName(), MainActivity.this);
                    return;
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

The only problem I'm facing is that even if I'm using option 1 and even if I'm using option 2, I'm ALWAYS getting false on the check. Meaning, say I click an app that requires manage external storage and it's state is currently not allowed. I click the app, I get moved to the appropriate screen, I allow the permission, I go back to the main screen, when I click the app again, instead of opening, I'm being moved to the same permission screen. Debugger shows that

```
getPackageManager().checkPermission(permission_string, packageName);
```

is returning false, even though the permission is given. Same for when I'm using option 2.
So my question is, what other methods are available to determine if a different app is granted a permission or, what am I doing wrong here in this code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After digging some more I've found AppOps.
This is the code I've used to work, Android 11:

```
AppOpsManager appOps = (AppOpsManager)getSystemService(Context.APP_OPS_SERVICE);
            ApplicationInfo applicationInfo = getPackageManager().getApplicationInfo(currAppInfo.getName(), 0);

            PackageInfo pi = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(currAppInfo.getName(), PackageManager.GET_PERMISSIONS);
            for(int i=0; i<pi.requestedPermissions.length; i++)
            {
                String perm = pi.requestedPermissions[i];
                PermissionInfo permi = getPackageManager().getPermissionInfo(perm, PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
                if(AppOpsManager.permissionToOp(permi.name) == null)
                    continue;
                boolean granted = (appOps.unsafeCheckOpNoThrow(AppOpsManager.permissionToOp(permi.name),applicationInfo.uid,currAppInfo.getName()) == AppOpsManager.MODE_ALLOWED);
                if(granted)
                    continue;
            }
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for "android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" permission. I think that for that, sadly, IPC is required: https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/content/PermissionChecker#checkSelfPermission(android.content.Context,java.lang.String)

Comment: Yes, I've noticed it's not 100% working for that and another permission which I currently don't remember. There's also another permission that's not even there to check if the app have it. I don't see how the link you provided solves that though? It checks the permission of the app calling it, what I need to do is check from app A if app B has a permission

Comment: Sorry, was wrong link. Correct one is: https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/content/PermissionChecker#checkCallingPermission(android.content.Context,java.lang.String,java.lang.String)

Comment: I remember seeing this but that it did not work for my needs but I no longer remember, I'll check it again at some point and will let you know, thanks :)

Comment: If you know about SAW permission (system alert window), please let me know.

Comment: Actually, I just checked my code, it seems PACKAGE_USAGE_STATS and ACCESS_NOTIFICATION_POLICY are the ones that seems this is not working for. SAW seems to be working for me with the code provided

Comment: Are you sure? You can check whether some app has SAW or not?

Comment: Well, it's already up and running on our system and I'm quite sure it's working for SAW as well. If I'll get to it I'll try checking it specifically but since we are using many apps in our system which some do use this permission and there are no errors reported I'm assuming it's working as intended

Comment: Can you please share a sample project on Github to show how you've performed this check of SAW on a different app (or update here by adding a function for the case of SAW permission) ?

Comment: I just checked. Assuming SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW requires the "shown above other apps" permission, the provided code here works and is able to identify if the app is granted SAW permission

Answer (score 1):

This is due to Android 11 restrictions to prevent installed apps fingerprinting.

You need to add target package name (e.g `com.termux`) to `queries` element or declare `QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES` permission in `AndroidManifest.xml` if `targetSdkVersion` is `30+`. Check [Package Visibility](https://developer.android.com/training/package-visibility#package-name) or [this article](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/working-with-package-visibility-dc252829de2d) for more info. Otherwise, you will will get `PackageSetting{...... com.termux/......} BLOCKED` errors in `logcat`.

```
<manifest
    <queries>
        <package android:name="com.termux" />
   </queries>
</manifest>
```

Comment: This is almost year old thread that was already answered...

Comment: You may have implemented an alternative, but that doesn't answer your original question/issue of "checkPermission() is returning false, even though the permission is given" and "what am I doing wrong here in this code". Others may find it useful even if you do not.

Comment: It might have been left out on my part how ever this piece of code should be able to get permissions on any package, even those installed after my app. Therefore, writing it in the xml does not solve the issue